# Which static library should I link when using wingdi.h?

Tags: c++, fltk

Recently I've tried FLTK. After I compiled the source code, I want to create a tiny application using FLTK.

[image: code]

However, after I tried to complie it, g++ said:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\FLTK\lib/libfltk.a(Fl_Window_shape.cxx.obj):Fl_Window_shape.cxx:(.text+0x298): undefined reference to '__imp_ExtCreateRegion' 
C:\Program Files (x86)\FLTK\lib/libfltk.a(Fl_Window_shape.cxx.obj):Fl_Window_shape.cxx:(.text+0x2c4): undefined reference to '__imp_CombineRgn'
C:\Program Files (x86)\FLTK\lib/libfltk.a(Fl_Window_shape.cxx.obj):Fl_Window_shape.cxx:(.text+0x2d4): undefined reference to '__imp_DeleteObject'
C:\Program Files (x86)\FLTK\lib/libfltk.a(Fl_Window_shape.cxx.obj):Fl_Window_shape.cxx:(.text+0x351): undefined reference to '__imp_ExtCreateRegion'
C:\Program Files (x86)\FLTK\lib/libfltk.a(Fl_Window_shape.cxx.obj):Fl_Window_shape.cxx:(.text+0x37d): undefined reference to '__imp_CombineRgn'
C:\Program Files (x86)\FLTK\lib/libfltk.a(Fl_Window_shape.cxx.obj):Fl_Window_shape.cxx:(.text+0x38d): undefined reference to '__imp_DeleteObject'
C:\Program Files (x86)\FLTK\lib/libfltk.a(fl_color.cxx.obj):fl_color.cxx:(.text+0x65): undefined reference to '__imp_DeleteObject'
C:\Program Files (x86)\FLTK\lib/libfltk.a(fl_color.cxx.obj):fl_color.cxx:(.text+0x9f): undefined reference to '__imp_CreatePen'
C:\Program Files (x86)\FLTK\lib/libfltk.a(fl_color.cxx.obj):fl_color.cxx:(.text+0xc3): undefined reference to '__imp_SelectObject'
C:\Program Files (x86)\FLTK\lib/libfltk.a(fl_color.cxx.obj):fl_color.cxx:(.text+0x102): undefined reference to '__imp_SelectObject'
```

And a lot more. I figured out that `ExtCreateRegion` and other mentioned functions are in `windgi.h`. So, which static library should I link to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most functions declared in `wingdi.h` require linking to `gdi32.lib`.

For example, `ExtCreateRegion` is [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-extcreateregion), and among the details at the bottom of that page are:

- Header:     wingdi.h  (include Windows.h)
- Library:     Gdi32.lib
- DLL:         Gdi32.dll

> which static library should I link?

`gdi32.lib` is not a *static* library, but rather is an *import* library that references `gdi32.dll`, which will be loaded at runtime and contains the actual function.